# Can't load an .xml file when run python program in raspberry pi3 at startup

Tags: python, debian, startup, raspberry-pi3

I have a python code in a raspberry pi3 with debian OS that use socket to connect a code in my laptop.In my python code, i run some c++ execute file.
My server python code in raspberry:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import sys
import time
import os
import SocketServer
import thread
import os.path
import webbrowser
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO



class MyTCPHandler(SocketServer.BaseRequestHandler):
    """
    The request handler class for our server.

    It is instantiated once per connection to the server, and must
    override the handle() method to implement communication to the
    client.
    """

    def handle(self):
        try:
            # self.request is the TCP socket connected to the client
            self.data = self.request.recv(1024).strip()
            print "{} wrote:".format(self.client_address[0])
            print self.data


            text1=self.data

            if text1=="Recognition":
               os.system("/home/pi/Desktop/shervin/build/WebcamFaceRec")
               f = open('/home/pi/Desktop/shervin/build/rec.txt', 'r')
               #print "rec-------------"
                   result=f.read()


            else:
                print text1
                print "This input is not valid!.."


            self.request.sendall(result)

        except Exception, e:
            print type(e)
            print e


if __name__ == "__main__":
    HOST, PORT = "192.168.1.55", 9998

    # Create the server, binding to localhost on port 9999
    try:
        server = SocketServer.TCPServer((HOST, PORT), MyTCPHandler)
        # Activate the server; this will keep running until you
        # interrupt the program with Ctrl-C
        server.serve_forever()
    except Exception, e:
            print type(e)
            print e
```

I want to run my code in start up of raspberry. I write

```
python pathaddress/pythoncodename.py
```

in .bashrc file with :

```
sudo nano .bashrc
```

it work correctly. But when run c++ execute file **WebcamFaceRec** ,in line of `os.system("/home/pi/Desktop/shervin/build/WebcamFaceRec")`, i see that cannot load .xml file.

in WebcamFaceRec.cpp i have this line code:

```
const char *faceCascadeFilename = "lbpcascade_frontalface.xml";     // LBP face detector.
    .
    .
     faceCascade.load(faceCascadeFilename);
```

When i run this python code manually without startup, all thing work correctly.
What i must do?

Comment: http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/8734/execute-script-on-start-up

Comment: @AminEtesamian, Thanks alot. it work correctly. but i faced another problem. in my python code i run an exe of c++ : "os.system("/home/pi/Desktop/shervin/build/WebcamFaceRec")". that in this exe i want to load an .xml file. and i see this error : ERROR: Could not load Face Detection cascade classifier [lbpcascade_frontalface.xml]!

Comment: @negar Edit the question and show us the code lotfan :)

Comment: @AminEtesamian, edited question is ready. :)